# lazy loading and $ocLazyLoad

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lazy-loading

I recently discovered the [$ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/docs/getting-started) third party angular module which enables lazy loading of javascript files. I'm a bit confused about this concept. How is lazy loading different than caching, and why would you want to lazy load when using angularjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

caching and lazy loading are two different concepts.

## caching

caching a file means that you will not require to go to the server to grab it again. instead you pull it from the browser's cache, saving http request time.

you can cache templates by inlining them in the html, this will save loading them from another file, but increase the initial loading time for the bytes size of those templates. in general its good to cache templates. and scripts aswell.

## lazy-loading

lazyloading means that the file will not be loaded (no http request will be made) only after the module is needed, then its loaded, its script is evaluated and executed.

you can lazyload and cache the file ofcourse. caching it using service workers, or relying on request headers and browser for caching.